# How to leave only the icon in the Me Menu?

Tags: gnome-panel, applet

I have a question, is it possible to display only the icon in Me Menu?

It is interesting, since I do not see much utility that contain the name, and let the cleaner look. I realized that only appears in OS Elementary icon.

So is it possible?

Thanks!!!

Sorry my bad english, I am Brazilian ;)

Elementary OS icon:

[image]

Ubuntu 10.10 - Me Menu:

[image: desciption]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this command:

`gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 0`

If you are using any version before 11.04, you might have to use `killall gnome-panel` for the change to appear.

Comment: No problem, just remember to mark this as the answer to your question if it worked for you.

Comment: As an added bonus, this got rid of my Me Menu entirely, leaving me with only a shutdown window. Some people might not like this, but for me it's awesome as I find the Me Menu to be thoroughly useless.

Comment: @mssever if you do killall gnome-panel I think the icon alone will return. If you want to remove the option entirely then it can easily be done through Ubuntu Tweak under Desktop > GNOME Settings > Panel Settings.